# Multiple authentication app support

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

When developing a Django project, many third party authentication packages are available, for example:

- `Django OAuth Toolkit`, OAuth 2.0 support.
- `Djoser`, provides a set of views to handle basic actions such as registration, login, logout, password reset and account activation.

Currently, I just want to support basic actions registration, login and so on. So `Djoser` could be my best choice.

But if I want to support OAuth 2.0 later, I will have two tokens, one is from `Djoser`, and another is from `Django OAuth Toolkit`. I just got confused here, how to handler two tokens at the same time?

Or should I just replace `Djoser` with `Django OAuth Toolkit`, if so, how to support basic actions such as registration?

Answer (score 0):

djoser supports only Basic Auth and the token auth by Django Rest Framework. What you can do is to make use of login and logout from Django OAuth Toolkit and then djoser views such as like register, password reset.